# Socket.io client how do i use the same session id for each diffrent webpage

Tags: javascript, socket.io

okay so i know how to show my socketid in my client code.

heres what i use for sessionid.

```
<script src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect('https://example-c9.c9.io/');
    socket.emit('Start', 'tobi', function (data) {
    var sessionid = socket.socket.sessionid;
    console.log(data + " " + sessionid); // data will be 'woot'
  });
</script>
```

Problem is i want to see what url is used to connect so i can use it later in another page
of my frontend

i am looking to get a url that looks like so

```
https://example.c9.c9.io/socket.io/1/?t=1396888886995
```

is there any way i can do this with socketio

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you trying to do, but I have two suggestions.

1.- You can send your current path to socket.io with an event.

2.- To know the url or path where the user gets connected you can do this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new connection', socket.handshake);
});
```

Comment: this is useless for me i am looking for client code to get the url and i am getting the url so i can use the same session when my html frontend pages change